# Does the multiarch feature in 11.10 mean the death of force--architecture installs?

Tags: 11.10, multiarch

Well does the multiarch feature of 11.10 mean 64bit users will be able to install 32bit '.debs' without resorting to the 'force--architecture' command?

Comment: Could you link to more information about this Multarch? I've never heard of such a thing before.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi: http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/Implementation, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/TechnicalOverview#Enabling_multiarch_if_you_upgraded_before_Beta-1

Comment: Muti architecture feature is what I meant. It seems that feature will mitigate the need for ia32 libraries or so I heard d

Comment: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-o-multiarch-next-steps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is indeed no need for `--force-architecture` anymore with multi-arch support with a some notes:

- The libraries on which the package depend must support Multi-arch
- Even if multi-arch is supported, it's possible for a library package to make the system install either the 32-bit version *or* the 64-bit one, but not both. So, the package in question should not have a need to depend on such a library unless there is no 64-bit equivalent necessary.
- Many packages from third-party websites do not set the necessary dependencies. Before multi-arch, a dirty hack called `ia32-libs` was created. This would contain the 32-bit libraries for multiple packages, and therefore it was easy for the maintainer to say "just install the `ia32-libs` package." In most cases, the dependencies are mentioned for the 32-bit sysems, so you should install those, but for the 32-bit architecture by adding `:i386` after each package as in:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386
  ```

Comment: wow! Ubuntu getting exciting by the day

Comment: Is this still valid for 12.04?

Comment: @belacqua Yes it is.