# Trouble compiling a 32 bit binary on a 64 bit machine

Tags: 32-bit, gcc

I'm trying to compile a c program as a 32 bit binary instead of 64 bit.  I started by just adding `-m32` and got some errors.  Googling around a little I came across a note to install ia32-libs.  Running `apt-get install ia32-libs` resulted in a notification taht it was already installed and at the newest version.

There is a chain of libraries each one including the next until it fails:

```
/usr/include/features.h:323:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
```

It seems to be including 32 bit versions of the other includes `/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/32/bits/ ...`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Lekensteyn's answer conflicted with lots of existing packages for me (on 64-bit oneiric).

I instead did this, which pulled in the `libc6-dev-i386` package:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

Answer (score 7):

`ia32-libs` just contains *some* compatibility libraries haven't been migrated yet to Multi Arch. For compiling 32-bit libraries, you need to install the 32-bit libraries and development files for C:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev:i386
```

See also: [Does the multiarch feature in 11.10 mean the death of force--architecture installs?](https://askubuntu.com/q/59778/6969)

Comment: Installing `libc6-dev:i386` insisted on removing the entire gnu compiler suite (which gave me a little heart attack) but after using `sudo apt-get install build-essential` everything worked perfectly.

Comment: For me, it also uninstalled nvidia-current... reinstalled with no problems though.

Comment: Note that the option given by alberge seems better in that it won't remove tons of other things for installing the 32-bit libraries.

Answer (score 0):

For those from future, this is a ten-year old question. Sadly none of the above solutions work for me.

Here is a similar but rather new one [How to compile 32-bit executable on 64 bit system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270351/how-to-compile-32-bit-executable-on-64-bit-system), and the solution of this fresh post does solve my problem.

Just install this:

```
sudo apt install libc6-dev-i386
```