# problem in making software

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make, makefile

I am trying to make an old version of lammps-13Jull11. I used this command in the src directory: `make openmpi`
but it failed because of these errors:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/alireza/lammps-13Jul11/src/Obj_openmpi'  
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h', needed by 'bond_fene.o'.  Stop.  
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/alireza/lammps-13Jul11/src/Obj_openmpi'  
Makefile:66: recipe for target 'openmpi' failed  
make: *** [openmpi] Error 2
```

Comment: Do you mean https://lammps.sandia.gov/ ? If so, you should start at https://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/Build or even go get a binary at https://lammps.sandia.gov/download.html

Comment: Yes I maen that. I think my problem is about linux. and i should add some package to it. [to make target '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h', needed by 'bond_fene.o']. I think it means there is not huge_val.h in that directory.

Comment: This is a bit too broad for this site. You are encouraged to either use the binaries provided or follow the instructions for building. If you still have issues, then ask the question in the context of that issue. However, it should be stressed that none of this is Ubuntu specific and so is off topic. You could try one of the other Stack Exchange sites dedicated to coding and compilation.

Comment: I think my problem is about linux. and i should add some package to it. [to make target '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h', needed by 'bond_fene.o']. I think it means there is not huge_val.h in that directory. I am similar with lammps.

Comment: "bits", I recall, is where architecture specific headers are placed. But, we don't even know if you have installed "build essentials", which is documented elsewhere. But this is not necessarily Ubuntu specific. I bet you could research over on Unix/Linux SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That being said, you don't say what your current Ubuntu is (what does uname -a say?) but this may be related: https://askubuntu.com/q/91909/459652

Comment: On MY Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS system (YMMV):  
  

    $ dpkg -S /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h
    libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h

I get my `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h` file from the `libc6-dev:amd64` package.

Answer (score 0):

On MY Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS system (YMMV):

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h
libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h
```

I get my `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h` file from the `libc6-dev:amd64` package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When i do:[$ dpkg -S /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h] i receive:[dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h].How can i get it from libc6-dev:amd64????