# How to compile 32-bit executable on 64 bit system

Tags: compiling, 32-bit

Note: I looked through some of the suggested "similar questions" and didn't find anything that looked conclusive.  Plus, it seems most of them are 6 years old (from 2014), so I'm hoping for something more up-to-date (and more likely to "just work").

I have a 64 bit Ubuntu system that works fine.  I would like to be able to build a 32 bit version of, say, "hello, world".  This is mostly an academic pursuit, but it would be convenient to get it working.  It would be nice if compiling with "-m32" would "just work", but it doesn't.  Worse, my memory is that this used to "just work" (in an older version of 64 bit Linux), but no longer works.

Observe:

```
$ cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { puts("hello, world"); return 0; }
$ gcc -m32 hello.c
In file included from hello.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:27:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
$
```

A bit of poking around suggests that installing these packages (see below) might help, so I did:

```
apt-get install libc6-dev-i386-x32-cross
```

which installed the following:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:


libc6-dev-i386-x32-cross libc6-dev-x32-cross libc6-i386-x32-cross
  libc6-x32-cross linux-libc-dev-x32-cross
```

After that, with a little bit of fudging, I was able to get it to compile, but not link.  The link phase gives these error msgs:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And I can't get any farther than that.

So, any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: FWIW it *does* just work on my system - which has `libc6-dev-i386` but **not** `libc6-dev-i386-x32-cross`

Comment: BTW I'm guessing your Ubuntu version is 18.04 based on references to gcc-7 - but you should really include this information in your question

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit

Comment: Relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/352783/43390

Answer (score 3):

You have to install correct development packages by

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libc6-dev-i386
```

And then it will work:

> ```
> $ gcc hello.c -o hello32 -m32
> $ file hello32
> hello32: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=444fafde1d2281a8af74adc452a8db046df1276e, not stripped
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Yup - it turns out all you have to do is install libc6-dev-i386 - then everything works.

Thanks for the tip!

Note: There is a lot of confusing and wrong information on the Internet...