# Cannot install ia32-libs on a 64 bit Ubuntu installation

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit

I am using a 64-bit installation of Oneiric. I need to install the ia32-libs package to get some applications (evince, adobe reader) to work. For example, adobe reader is giving the following error: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

However, I am not able to install it since it is showing a dependency on ia32-libs-multiarch, which in turn is showing a dependency on gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386. This in turn depends on few other packages.

How can I install these packages safely and still meet all the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Install the dependencies as usual, but append `:i386` to it as in:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

If you get an impossible situation, try to install the 32-bit C library first, then the other packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
```

See also [Does the multiarch feature in 11.10 mean the death of force--architecture installs?](https://askubuntu.com/q/59778/6969)

Comment: Thank you @Lekensteyn, but it is still not working. The root dependency is gsettings-desktop-schema:i386, and when I try to install it, it tries to uninstall other important packages.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this worked for me

Create this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences
```

and insert the following lines:

```
Package: *       
Pin: release a=quantal*
Pin-Priority: 2012
```

Ctrl-X to quit and Y to save

Then do a downgrade:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then install ia32-libs

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Don't forget to delete the preferences file you created so that other updates will be found!

`sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences`

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly, just do what it says after the failed force install I.E.:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This apparently runs a forced install on failed dependency packages for the previous command and resolved my issues for installing Adobe Acrobat 9.5.1 in Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

try to add i386 to your multiarch prefs

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
```